# Sources for good summaries of candidates' political positions

Tags: united-states, election

What reliable sources are available for statements by US political candidates, particularly in summary form? Reliable sources for past actions of these candidates would also be useful.

Comment: Are you looking for just the presidential candidates?  All office holders?  For example, there's a lot of information about past actions for Congresspeople and governors, less so for others.

Comment: Anything I can get, though primarily national or state, rather than municipal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I often look at the Wikipedia pages for individual candidates.  They usually have a "political positions" section for major candidates.

[Project Vote Smart](http://votesmart.org/) tries to provide objective information about candidate positions.  Also links to other evaluations and additional information.

[On the Issues](http://www.ontheissues.org/default.htm) sends out questionnaires and tracks candidate responses and other statements.

[I Side With](https://www.isidewith.com/) offers a [quiz](https://www.isidewith.com/elections/2016-presidential-quiz) to match people to presidential candidates.  It asks a series of questions on popular issues and then tries to find the closest match among the candidates.